# Sub Domain Not Working on Nginx server with Apache Handling PHP

Tags: nginx, php, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4

I have a domain setup and it is working. However I cannot get any sub domains working. I am trying to setup a sub domain right now for phpmyadmin. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache with PHP. This works fine for the main domain, Nginx is handling the static content and Apache is handling the PHP. When I setup a sub domain I just get a 404 stating it cannout find /index.php.

I have a server blocks set for the main domain and the sub domain, each in a separate file and linked to sites-enabled. I have the A record setup for the sub domain.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong for this to not work?

My server blocks are setup as follows

Main domain:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Sub domain

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;
    server_name pma.example.com;

    location / {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show any log snippets. BTW, having Apache installed just to serve PHP is a big waste - use PHP-FPM

Comment: Thanks, I ended up switching over to PHP-FPM and it's all working now.